# Jest & Config Issue: SyntaxError Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: next.js, jestjs, turbo

I am trying to setup Jest for testing in my NextJS application on a monorepo. I followed the guide on the [official NextJS doc](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/optimizing/testing#jest-and-react-testing-library) that uses the Rest Compiler, then I configured babel, but for some reason when I try to run a `pnpm test` I get an issues stating that "Jest encountered an unexpected token".

Also in the error message details it shows that Jest is looking at the `node_modules` folder of the parent directory and not the `web` node_modules of the application where my `jest.config.ts` file is located.

[Screenshot of project directories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vYUgX.png)

I have tried to set my `jest.config.ts` file to explicitly state the location of my `modulePaths` & `moduleDirectories` but that doesn't seem to help. Can anyone give me some advice.

Here is my `jest.config.ts` file.

```
const nextJest = require("next/jest");

// Providing the path to your Next.js app which will enable loading next.config.js and .env files
const createJestConfig = nextJest({ dir: "./" });

// Any custom config you want to pass to Jest
const customJestConfig = {
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ["<rootDir>/src/test/jest.setup.js"],
  testEnvironment: "jest-environment-jsdom",
  moduleDirectories: ["<rootDir>/node_modules"],
  modulePaths: ["<rootDir>/"],
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.(ts|tsx)?$': 'ts-jest',
    "^.+\\.(js|jsx)$": "babel-jest",
  },
};

// createJestConfig is exported in this way to ensure that next/jest can load the Next.js configuration, which is async
module.exports = createJestConfig(customJestConfig);
```

**Spec**

```bash
NextJS: 13.4.1
Turbo Repo
```